# Receiving a runtime error, see photo, during run. Want to expand a spiral matrix

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am at a lost and I am posting all my code so that I can get the situation resolved. I am relatively new to programming and teaching myself C++ with Dr. Bronson's textbook.

Here is the error I get:

[image: Errror Statement]

Here is my code. When I put a "cout" statement at the head of the int main(), I still get the same error.

```
// 28.PE.NumberSpiralMatrix.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std;

const int ROW = 1001;
const int COL = 1001;
int right(int spiral[ROW][COL], int, int, int, int);
int down(int spiral[ROW][COL], int, int, int);
int left(int spiral[ROW][COL], int, int, int, int);
int up(int spiral[ROW][COL], int, int, int);


int main()
{
    cout << "We are here!" << endl; 

    int spiral[ROW][COL];
    int crow = 4;
    int ccol = 4;
    int i, j;
    int growth = 1, count = 0, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0;
    int inc; 

    for (inc = 0; inc < 501; inc++)//increased by 1
    {

        growth = right(spiral, growth, count, count1, inc);
        count++;
        if (count <= 3 + inc)//Increasing the count by one and count1 increased the column number. Common sense but hard to see.  
        {
            count1++;
        }
        //cout << growth << endl; 
        if (growth == 1002002)
        {
            break;
        }
        growth = down(spiral, growth, count2, inc);
        if (count2 < 3 + inc)// increased by 1 from 5 to 7; 
        {
            count2++;
        }
        //cout << growth << endl; 

        growth = left(spiral, growth, count3, count4, inc);
        //cout << growth << endl; 
        if (count3 <= 3 + inc)//Increased by 1 from 5 to 7. 
        {
            count3++;
        }
        if (count4 <= 4 + inc)//Increased by 1 from 5 to 7. 
        {
            count4++;
        }

        growth = up(spiral, growth, count5, inc);
        //cout << growth << endl;
        if (count5 < 4+inc)//increased by 1 from 5 to 7; 
        {
            count5++;
        }


    }


    return 0;
}

int right(int spiral[ROW][COL], int Growth, int Count, int Count1, int inc)
{
    int i, j;
    int count1 = 0;
    int step;

    cout << "Welcome, I am here in right." << endl;

    for (j = (4+inc) - Count; j <= ((5+inc) + Count1); j++) // Count: 0 --> 2. Increased by 1, 5 to 7.   
    {
        step = (4+inc) - Count; // increased by 1, 5 to 7
        spiral[step][j] = Growth;
        Growth++;
        cout << spiral[step][j] << " " << "i: " << step << ", j: " << j << endl;
    }
    cout << "Growth is: " << Growth << endl;

    return Growth;
}

int down(int spiral[ROW][COL], int Growth, int Count2, int inc)
{
    int i;
    int step;
    int count2 = 0;

    cout << "Welcome, I am here in down." << endl;

    for (i = (5+inc) - Count2; i <= (5+inc) + Count2; i++)// increased by 1 from 5 to 7. 
    {
        step = (5 + inc) + Count2; // increased by 1 from 5 to 7. 
        spiral[i][step] = Growth;
        Growth++;
        cout << spiral[i][step] << ", " << "i: " << i << ", " << "j: " << step << endl;

    }

    return Growth;
}

int left(int spiral[ROW][COL], int Growth, int Count3, int Count4, int inc)
{
    int j;
    int step;

    cout << "Welcome, I am here in left." << endl;

    for (j = (4+inc) + Count3; j >= (3+inc) - Count3; j--) // Count3 and Count4
    {
        step = (5+inc) + Count3;
        spiral[step][j] = Growth;
        Growth++;
        cout << spiral[step][j] << ", " << "i: " << step << ", " << "j: " << j << endl;
    }

    return Growth;
}

int up(int spiral[ROW][COL], int Growth, int Count5, int inc)
{
    int i;
    int step;

    cout << "Welcome, I am here in up." << endl;
    for (i = (4+inc) + Count5; i >= (4+inc) - Count5; i--)//increased by one from 5 to 7; 
    {
        step = (3+inc) - Count5; //increased by one from 5 to 7. 
        spiral[i][step] = Growth;
        Growth++;
        cout << spiral[i][step] << ", " << "i: " << i << ", " << "j: " << step << endl;
    }

    return Growth;
}
```

Comment: You may not have heard this yet, but in a case like this you should reduce your code to a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And not just for posting here; it's a vital skill for any good programmer.

Comment: You seem to be running past the end of your array `spiral`, but since you haven't explained what you want this code to do, it's hard to say where the error lies.

Comment: The issue is more than likely your arrays are too large for the stack.  `1001 * 1001 * sizeof(int)`, if `sizeof(int) == 4` is 4 megabytes.  Use `std::vector` instead of two dimensional arrays.

Comment: Beta, I said in the subject that I want to expand a spiral matrix. A matrix that starts with 1 in the center.

Comment: @HappyS5 *Dr. Bronson's textbook.* -- Did the textbook recommend declaring local arrays that are 4 megabytes in size?  You're not going anywhere until you move that array outside of `main` (make it global) or use `std::vector` and less recommended, allocate from the heap.  So basically just move that array outside of main and see if the program starts to run.

Comment: Thanks Paul Mckenzie.

Comment: Try first 3x3, then 4x4, then 5x5 - if it works well - your code is workable. You must realize and understand SPACE issues.
I can give your simple workable example of spiral matrix initialization in C#.  Your matrix 500x500 it runs in 7! seconds.

Comment: Thanks Gleb B. I appreciate your comment!